# Get list of a class' instance methods

Tags: ruby, reflection, ruby-1.9.2

I have a class:

```
class TestClass
  def method1
  end

  def method2
  end

  def method3
  end
end
```

How can I get a list of my methods in this class (`method1`, `method2`, `method3`)?

Answer (score 126, accepted):

You actually want `TestClass.instance_methods`, unless you're interested in what `TestClass` itself can do.

```
class TestClass
  def method1
  end

  def method2
  end

  def method3
  end
end

TestClass.methods.grep(/method1/) # => []
TestClass.instance_methods.grep(/method1/) # => ["method1"]
TestClass.methods.grep(/new/) # => ["new"]
```

Or you can call `methods` (not `instance_methods`) on the object:

```
test_object = TestClass.new
test_object.methods.grep(/method1/) # => ["method1"]
```

Comment: Heh, you beat me to it by 47 seconds. +1

Comment: When i try `print TestClass.new.instance_methods`, i get this error `my_class.rb:10:in <main>: undefined method instance_methods for #<TestClass:0x96b9d20> (NoMethodError)`

Comment: You only need to do `TestClass.new.methods`. Maybe "it" was ambiguous in my answer.

Comment: Note that under Ruby 1.9+ the array of method names are symbols, not strings.

Comment: @Phrogz: Yes, but you're allowed to use regular expressions on them. You don't even summon Cthulhu! :) Though you would get `[:method1]` instead.

Answer (score 130):

```
TestClass.methods(false)
```

to get only methods that belong to that class only.

`TestClass.instance_methods(false)` 
would return the methods from your given example (since they are instance methods of TestClass).

Comment: This is great way to test if a class has polymorphed methods from a pseudo-Interface/Abstract base class without having to try and call the methods directly.

Comment: Accepted answer is great but this one is likely what more people will come here for!

Comment: This definitely should be the accepted answer. THANKS!

Comment: @Aaron: I highly doubt that, since this answer is *wrong*. `Object#methods` returns the methods that you can *call* on an *object*. What are the methods you can call on an object? The ones that are defined in its *class*. Which means that `TestClass.methods` returns the list of methods you can *call* on `TestClass`, which are the methods that are defined in its class. What is `TestClass`'s class? It is `Class`. So, `TestClass.methods` gives you the methods that are defined in `Class`, not the ones that are defined in `TestClass`. Not sure how this answer got 116 upvotes, when anybody with even

Comment: … the most remote passing knowledge would instantly recognize it as wrong. Or, you know, just copy&pasting this code and running it would reveal that it is wrong.

Comment: @ViniciusBrasil: This answer is wrong, so it should *definitely not* be the accepted answer, and the fact that it has 116 upvotes is seriously sad, considering that it takes 1 second to just copy&paste the code and try it out, and less than one second to just think it through.

Comment: I can't recall what was going on 4+ years ago so I'll offer my best guess. The currently accepted answer is thorough and provides a great understanding of the differences between `Object#methods` and `Object#instance_methods`. I imagine that I found this answer's usage of the `false` argument to be what I was interested in as `TestClass.instance_methods.size` is 64 on Ruby 2.7.1 but `TestClass.instance_methods(false).size` is limited to the three defined. I probably was lazy and didn't want to chain `grep` ‍♂️

Answer (score 42):

```
TestClass.instance_methods
```

or without all the inherited methods

```
TestClass.instance_methods - Object.methods
```

(Was 'TestClass.methods - Object.methods')

Comment: or without inherited methods: `TestClass.methods(false)`.

Comment: @sawa `TestClass.methods(false)` returns empty

Comment: This answer is wrong; the results will not include `method1`, `method2`, or `method3`, as those are methods of _instances_ of the class, not methods of the `TestClass` object itself.

Comment: @Phrogz: Oops... yes, 'TestClass.instance_methods - Object.methods', or 'TestClass.new.methods - Object.methods'... that'll teach me for not firing up a console. Is it best for me to delete this answer, or edit it?

Comment: @Phrogz - this answer works for me, i get _[:method1, :method2, :method3]_ with `print TestClass.new.methods - Object.methods`

Comment: @Vladimir @Phrogz The question was contradictory. In the title (before the edit by Theo), it was asking for class methods, and in the body, it's asking for `method1`, etc.

Comment: @Pavling Definitely edit your answer to be correct. (Quickly, before the OP assigns the credit to someone else! :)

Comment: @Phrogz: Keeping the (corrected) answer is also a good way of showing a potential "gotcha".

Answer (score 7):

```
$ irb --simple-prompt

class TestClass
  def method1
  end

  def method2
  end

  def method3
  end
end

tc_list = TestClass.instance_methods(false)
#[:method1, :method2, :method3]
puts tc_list
#method1
#method2
#method3
```

Answer (score 5):

You can get a more detailed list (e.g. structured by defining class) with gems like [debugging](https://github.com/janlelis/debugging#mofobj-depth--nil) or [looksee](https://github.com/oggy/looksee).

Answer (score 5):

According to Ruby Doc [instance_methods](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Module.html#method-i-instance_method)

> Returns an array containing the names of the public and protected
>   instance methods in the receiver. For a module, these are the public
>   and protected methods; for a class, they are the instance (not
>   singleton) methods. If the optional parameter is false, the methods of
>   any ancestors are not included.
>   I am taking the official documentation example.

```
module A
  def method1()  
    puts "method1 say hi"
  end
end
class B
  include A #mixin
  def method2()  
     puts "method2 say hi"
  end
end
class C < B #inheritance
  def method3() 
     puts "method3 say hi"
  end
end
```

Let's see the output.

```
A.instance_methods(false)
  => [:method1]

A.instance_methods
  => [:method1]
B.instance_methods
 => [:method2, :method1, :nil?, :===, ...# ] # methods inherited from parent class, most important :method1 is also visible because we mix module A in class B

B.instance_methods(false)
  => [:method2]
C.instance_methods
  => [:method3, :method2, :method1, :nil?, :===, ...#] # same as above
C.instance_methods(false)
 => [:method3]
```

Answer (score 2):

To get only own methods, and exclude inherited ones:

From within the instance:

```
self.methods - self.class.superclass.instance_methods
```

From outside:

```
TestClass.instance_methods - TestClass.superclass.instance_methods
```

Add it to the class:

```
class TestClass
  class << self
    def own_methods
      self.instance_methods - self.superclass.instance_methods
    end
  end
end

TestClass.own_methods
=> [:method1, :method2, :method3]
```

(with ruby 2.6.x)

Answer (score 0):

If you have an instance but don't know the class name:

```
object.class.instance_methods(false)
# => Array of class instance methods
```