# Can I reflect all the methods of a class in Ruby

Tags: ruby, reflection

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get list of a class' methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6468268/get-list-of-a-class-methods)

Suppose I haven't any reference on hand, and I want to see all the methods in the built-in File class, is that simply available?

---------------------------EDIT---------------------------

answered in [Get list of a class' instance methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6468268/get-list-of-a-class-methods)

Comment: This *exact same question* was already asked and answered many times here on StackOverflow, the last time was just *yesterday*, 18.5 hours before this one. How much can the Ruby language have changed between then and now, that this question needs to be asked *again*? Especially considering that the answer to *this* question is just plain wrong ...

Comment: @Jorg W Mittag: The answer that was originally accepted for that question was also just plain wrong. I think this question needs to be repeated until the fastest gun posts the correct answer!

Comment: Besides the answer mentioned above, you can always drop to the command line and use `ri File`. `ri` also works for gems if you let `gem` build the docs. There's also `gem server` if you want to use a browser.

Answer (score 3):

Sure, try:

```
File.methods
```

And if you have the [awesome_print](https://rubygems.org/gems/awesome_print) gem installed then it formats the list nicely and provides extra information.

Comment: See the question this duplicates to see why this is incorrect.

Comment: It's not "incorrect"; I know it gives you only the class level methods on `File`, but since the questioner didn't specify exactly which set of methods they want I gave the most basic information that I thought they could extrapolate from. I definitely don't think it deserves vote downs!

Comment: "I know it gives you only the class level methods on File" - if you knew that, you should have said so in the answer.