# How can one get the list of undefined methods in a Ruby class?

Tags: ruby, reflection

While playing a bit with Ruby, I wrote the following code:

```rb
class A
end

A.singleton_class.instance_eval do
    undef_method :new
end

# or
# class << B
#   undef_method :new
# end

A.new

> NoMethodError: undefined method `new' for A:Class
>         from (irb):8
>         from /home/mmsequeira/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/bin/irb:16:in `<main>'
```

This is cool. But how can I know which methods have been undefined in a given class?

Comment: You can't. Why do you need to know?

Comment: Just exploring Ruby. Ruby's reflection is very good, so it seems odd that one cannot get this information.

Comment: This answer may provide some additional insight for you.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6468268/get-list-of-a-class-methods

Comment: @allareri I don't think so.

Comment: Thanks! I guess I could use `Class.instance_methods - A.methods` for class methods, `T.superclass.instance_methods - T.instance_methods` for instance (non-singleton) methods, and `T.instance_methods - t.methods` for singleton methods. But still, that would leave out methods defined and then undefined in the class itself.

Comment: FWIW Ruby does keep track of undefined methods internally (`VM_METHOD_TYPE_UNDEF` -- that's how it ensures a future call won't land on e.g. a base class implementation, see [differences between `undef_method` and `remove_method`](http://www.nach-vorne.de/2008/2/28/undef_method-remove_method/index.html)), but looking at the Ruby source I fail to see a way of retrieving a list of these methods short of writing native code.

Comment: @vladr Right, it stores it internally but there's no way to get at them without writing a C extension that reaches into the core.

Comment: Seems like an oversight of Ruby's reflection API, @AndrewMarshall.

Comment: @MMSequeira oversight may not be the reason; more likely, the thought may have been that since you can't do anything with it (such as un-`undef` it) then why need you know that it exists? In other words, if it no longer quacks, do you really need to know that it used to be a duck?

Comment: If I store the method, I can un-undef it: `class A; def foo; "A#foo"; end; end; foo = A.instance_method :foo; class A; undef foo; end; A.instance_eval { define_method :foo, foo }`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't by default. Undefining a method removes it from existence. You could, however, record them as they're removed. This can be done with [method hooks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5168554/211563) to capture everything and avoid ugly alias method chaining:

```
class Module
  def method_undefined name
    (@undefined_methods ||= []) << name
  end

  def singleton_method_undefined name
    (@undefined_methods ||= []) << name
  end

  def undefined_methods
    @undefined_methods || []
  end
end
```

This will capture methods undefined via `undef_method` or `undef`:

```
class C
  def foo; end
  def bar; end

  undef foo
  undef_method :bar
end

C.undefined_methods  #=> [:foo, :bar]
C.singleton_class.instance_eval { undef new }
C.singleton_class.undefined_methods  #=> [:new]
```

Of course, you must include the hook methods in Module before anything can be captured.

Comment: That is much prettier and has generality than mine.

Comment: @sawa Thanks `:)`. Took me a while to realize `singleton_method_undefined` was a thing.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need to redefine `Module#undef_method`.

```
class Module
  alias original_undef_method :undef_method
  @@undef_methods = {}
  def undef_method *methods
    methods.each{|method| @@undef_methods[[self, method]] ||= true}
    original_undef_method(*methods)
  end
  def self.undef_methods; @@undef_methods.keys end
end
```

Then, you get:

```
class A
end
A.singleton_class.instance_eval do
    undef_method :new
end
Module.undef_methods
# => [[#<Class:A>, :new]]
```

Comment: This won't capture methods undefined with the `undef` keyword instead of `undef_method` method.

Comment: That is right. I thought that was what is asked. If the OP wanted to capture `undef` as well, it can be easily extended.

Comment: Not really, `undef` is a keyword so it cannot be overridden without changing the Ruby source and recompiling.

Comment: Nice idea. However, I would only get the methods undefined after aliasing.

Comment: @MMSequeira That should not matter unless you are trying to undefine `undef_method`, in which case it is going to be a mess.