# Method to find just my custom methods I wrote, not any inherited methods (Ruby)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5.2

```
class Foo

   def initialize()
   end

   def cow
   end

   def dog
   end

   def any_other
   end
end
```

What method can I use to find just my custom defined methods, cow, dog, and any_other,  and not any of the base methods?

```
Foo.custom_methods
>>
:cow
:dog
:any_other
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6468268/get-list-of-a-class-instance-methods

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Foo.instance_methods(false)` to get the instance methods, and `Foo.methods(false)` to get the class methods.

The `false` argument is saying *dont show inherited methods*.